# Best approach to convert XML to RDF/XML using an ontology

Tags: php, xml, mapping, rdf, ontology

I have an XML which uses the XPDL standard (which has an XML schema). What I'm trying to do now is to convert its content to RDF format (serialized in XML), in terms of a certain ontology. Clearly, there needs to be some sort of mapping here. I would like to do this using PHP. The thing is, I have no idea how to do this best. I know how to read an XML file, but how would the mappings occur? What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **XSLT**.  When transforming one flavor of XML into another it is often the best and easiest solution.

The mappings would occur in template matches for the XPDL elements that generate the RDF `Description` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a generic XML to RDF converter that works without an ontology at

http://www.gac-grid.org/project-products/Software/XML2RDF.html
(or sourceforge.net/projects/xmltordf/).

Maybe this can solve your problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to http://xsparql.deri.org

Answer (score -3):

Maybe nothing. Because RDF is an extension to XML or another flavor of XML. So I will say you: "Do nothing.".

Comment: No, RDF is a data model on its own and there is an XML syntax to represent RDF, which is one of the possible representations RDF can have. An XML document follows the rules of a given data model (i.e., an XML schema), which usually has nothing to do with RDF and RDF representation in XML. That's why you need to convert between the two.